# Making shortcuts run minimized in NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

In Windows, one can edit a shortcut's properties and choose whether it should start the target program's window normally, minimized, or maximized.

I'm creating an installer in NSIS, and there are some batch files to which I would like to create shortcuts and have them start minimized. Does anyone what parameters to include in `CreateShortcut` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a very basic example of a shortcut that starts the target minimized.  The empty strings are for additional parameters that are neglected in this example.  For more information, [see the reference](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.3.4)

```
CreateShortCut "MyShortcut.lnk" "MyProgram.exe" "" "" "" SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
```